# How can I automatically logout a user in React JS when their token has expired, as indicated by the "exp" field in the decoded token?

Tags: reactjs, jwt, mern

My issue with my current code is,it is not automatically redirecting to signIn page when token expires,but after token expire if I am refreshing the page manually ,then it redirects to signIn page.plzzzz check my code and give any solution.....
My code i:

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Navigate, useRoutes, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import JwtDecode from "jwt-decode";
// layouts
import DashboardLayout from './layouts/dashboard';
import SimpleLayout from './layouts/simple';

// pages

import SignIn from './pages/Auth/SignIn';
import SignUp from './pages/Auth/SignUp';
import Otp from './pages/Auth/Otp';


import Dashboard from './pages/Dashboard/AppAnalytics';

import AlumniListing from './pages/Alumni/AlumniListing';

import Page404 from './pages/Page404';

import Profile from './pages/Profile/index';
import EditProfile from './pages/EditProfile/index';
import Payment from './pages/Auth/Payment';
import PaymentStatus from './pages/Auth/PaymentStatus';
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

export default function Router() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const auth = localStorage.getItem("token");
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const checkLogin = () => {
    if (auth) {
      try {
        const decodedToken = JwtDecode(auth);
        const expiration = new Date(decodedToken?.exp * 1000);
        console.log('decodedToken:', decodedToken);
        console.log('expiration:', expiration.getTime);
        const currentTime = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
        if (currentTime >= decodedToken.exp) {
          console.log("JWT has expired or will expire soon");
          setIsLoggedIn(false);
          localStorage.removeItem("token");
        } else {
          console.log("JWT is valid for more than 5 minutes");
          setIsLoggedIn(true);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error decoding JWT:", error);
        setIsLoggedIn(false);
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
      }
    } else {
      setIsLoggedIn(false);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkLogin();
    if (!isLoggedIn) {
      navigate("/auth/sign-in");
    } else {
      navigate("/dashboard/analytics");
    }
  }, [auth,]);

  const routes = useRoutes([
    // {
    //   path: '/',
    //   element: <checkLogin />
    // },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      element: isLoggedIn ? <DashboardLayout /> : <Navigate to='/auth/sign-in' />,
      children: [
        { element: <Navigate to="/dashboard/analytics" />, index: true },
        { path: 'analytics', element: <Dashboard /> },
        { path: 'alumni', element: <AlumniListing /> },
        { path: 'profile', element: <Profile /> },
        { path: 'edit-profile', element: <EditProfile /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: 'auth/sign-in',
      element: !isLoggedIn ? <SignIn /> : <Navigate to='/dashboard/analytics' />,
    },
    {
      path: 'payment',
      element: <Payment />,
    },
    {
      path: 'payment/gateway-response',
      element: <PaymentStatus />,
    },
    {
      path: 'verify-otp',
      element: !isLoggedIn ? <Otp /> : <Navigate to='/dashboard/analytics' />,
    },
    {
      path: 'auth/sign-up',
      element: !isLoggedIn ? <SignUp /> : <Navigate to='/dashboard/analytics' />,
    },
    {
      element: <SimpleLayout />,
      children: [
        { path: '404', element: <Page404 /> },
        { path: '*', element: <Navigate to="/404" /> },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      element: <Navigate to="/404" replace />,
    },
  ]);

  return routes;
}
```

when I am consoling decodedToken,I am getting :

```
    {payload: {…}, iat: 1675398393, exp: 1675398453}
exp
: 
1675398453
iat
: 
1675398393
payload
: 
email
: 
"uma.swain@cybrain.co.in"
id
: 
"58332666-806d-4d4f-81b5-efb331acd4e2"
index
: 
"6730c5c3-c558-44d8-b771-2661f2c28a2a"
tenant
: 
"sales.alumni.cybraintech.in"
timestamp
: 
"2023-02-03T04:26:33.296Z"
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
[[Prototype]]
: 
Object
```

Thanks in advance.....

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a library called **AuthBee** for the same use case which can be used for any javascript project.

You can use it to get your job done.

You can find more on the library [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/authbee)

[example](https://github.com/shakyapeiris/AuthBee/tree/main/example)